# Why photo image is not referenced in tkinter Label object?

Tags: python, tkinter

There are a few related questions about label image been garbage collected. People usually suggest keep a reference to the photo `label.image = photoImage` to prevent gc. But I'm still confused. I thought when creating Label object

```
labelImg = tk.Label(window, image=photoImage, width=81, height=81)
```

photo image is passed as a parameter, so `labelImg` object should already has a reference to it.
If it does not, what does the constructor do to the passed-in `potoImage` object?

Here is an exmaple code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = tk.Tk()
window .geometry('400x510')
window.resizable(0, 0)

for n in range(5):
  image = Image.open('img.jpg')
  photoImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image.resize((81, 81)))
  labelImg = tk.Label(window, image=photoImage, width=81, height=81)
  labelImg.place(relx=0, rely=0.2*n)
  # labelImg.image = photoImage  without this line, only last photo image is shown.

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you are talking of `labelImg` then it is a label of width and height 81 to which you have provided image instead of text.

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't work the way you think — it does **not** create a reference to the photo image — that is why you need to do it yourself. In this case just add a `labelImg.img = photoImage` after creating the `Label`.

Comment: @TanishkaVashisht: [`Label`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/label.html) widgets  may also have an image.

Comment: @martineau I think so. I may need to look into the code to see how Label object is contructed.

Comment: If it's created in some function (or method), see [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function). This is a common problem and is because basically there what I would consider a bug in `tkinter` in this regard.